# How to rollback MySQL table after update Statement

Tags: mysql

By mistake, I executed MySQL command in command line without where condition.

```
update actor set first_name = 'Ved' , last_name ='Prakash';
```

it updated my all 500 rows with same first_name and last_name. any possibility to restore or rollback. I don't have the backup.

Comment: if you have not autocommit ON and the query is not committed  you can try rollback

Comment: @scaisEdge i did rollback command but no any row affected  mysql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: Then you have autocommit ON and the action can't be reverted .. you must load your last table backup ..

Comment: Sadly, if you don't have the backup - there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you start to writing sql command in MySQL.

Remember `autocommit =0`
then you use `rollback` otherwise not possible.

**Hope this help you for next MySQL command**